# php str_replace() doesn't delete white spaces

Tags: php

I have a form that passes values ​​to a php page. I have to convert a string by eliminating the white spaces and adding `-` or another (for example `,` or  `&nbsp;`).

If I write `VINI E BEVANDE` everything works.

However, if I have `$tipopiatto = "VINI E BEVANDE";` or `$tipopiatto = "VINI E BEVANDE";` it doesn't work and the spaces remain, where am I going wrong?

I try using this basic instruction and working fine

```
 $tipopiatto="VINI E BEVANDE";
 echo str_replace(' ', '-', "$tipopiatto");
```

...but if i try use this code, the script doesn't delete the white space

```
 $tipopiatto=$_POST['tipopiatto'];
 echo str_replace(' ', '-', "$tipopiatto");
```

Comment: Try printing `$_POST['tipopiatto']` and also the type of the variable `gettype($_POST['tipopiatto'])`. And share the result here.

Comment: and also, why on earth are you doing `"str_replace(' ', '-', "$tipopiatto");`? you don't need to inject the variable in a empty string, just use `str_replace(' ', '-', $tipopiatto);`

Comment: echo gettype($_POST['tipopiatto]); result---string

Comment: Try `preg_replace('/\s/', '-', $tipopiatto);` to replace whitespace characters instead of str_replace and check if it works!

Comment: Berto99 does not work even in this case, already tried

Comment: bhaumik 1987, don't work

Comment: You haven't shown us the value when you print `$_POST['tipopiatto'] ` as @Aashishgaba asked yet. Do a `var_dump( $_POST['tipopiatto'] );` and copy & paste in *exactly* what this prints out. Also, extra information should go in your question, not in your comments where they can be missed or not formatted correctly.

Comment: string(16) "VINI E BEVANDE"

Comment: Try to add `u` parameter for regex pattern `preg_replace('/\s+/u', '-', $tipopiatto);`

Comment: Thank you Bhaumik 1987, this instruction work fine

Comment: Code in comments is unreadable but `VINI E BEVANDE` doesn't have 16 bytes. I count 14. That pretty much explains the issue.

Answer (score 0):

While the tip about using preg_replace with the **u** parameter certainly works, do you really want to use the heavier preg_replace() when str_replace() is lighter and achieves the desired result?  The problem here might deceptively appear to be str_replace(), but in truth it probably more likely concerns the $_POST variable which needs to be inspected to see if its value is even valid. And, just in case there may be problematic input, I attempt to nullify any problems with the use of [htmlspecialchars](https://www.php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php)().

I tried the following code at home on my setup:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['myBtn']) )
    {
         if ( isset( $_POST['tipopiatto'] ) && ($_POST['tipopiatto'] != null )) {
             $tipopiatto= htmlspecialchars($_POST['tipopiatto']);
             echo str_replace(' ', '-', "$tipopiatto"); 
         }
         else
        {
            exit("Problematic input");
        }
}    
?>
<html>
<head><title>exp button click</title>
</head>

<body bgcolor="#ffffde">
<form method="POST" action="">
<input name="tipopiatto" type="text" value="VINI E BEVANDE">
<button type="submit" name="myBtn" id="myBtn">Submit</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

All the user needs to do is delete the forms text input value and when the form is submitted str_replace() will fail to give the expected result.  Moral of the story is that $_POST variables always need to be inspected and validated before use, otherwise the results may be disappointing and difficult to understand.

You may also wish to see a [live example](https://3v4l.org/irEIg) which is slightly different using a fake POST variable but drives the point home using PHP's 7 null coalescing operator.